# Keep timers running in background Apps without location services

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there a way to keep timers running when an App enters background mode without location services running?

If I have a timer running in the App with location services on and enter the background then it keeps running.  However calling stopUpdatingLocation also stops the timer.  I would like the timer to be able to call startUpdatingLocation at some point in the furture but as it not being run it can't do this.

Any information on how multi-tasking works with location services would be helpful.

Comment: i am facing same problem I want to update timer also when app running in background and want to save battery life too.for that need to update location at every perticular time interval and time during that location manager  should remain  stop

Answer (score 0):

You should probably figure out when (at what time) the timer would call startUpdatingLocation and add a UILocalNotification at that time.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I've tried using UILocalNotification but can't get it to work without it displaying a message on the screen when the App is in the background.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yourNotification.hasAction = NO;

Comment: @Larsaronen how add UILocalNotification in startUpdatingLocation method?